# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined on json_encode()

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So I am trying for 2 hours now, and I am still not able to get what's wrong with my code. I have created a simple XMLHttpRequest which gets information from a PHP page which is some data from the database. This is what I have done:

```
var xhr2 = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xhr2.open('GET', 'admin/images_data.php');
xhr2.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
    var album_photos = eval(xhr2.responseText);
    console.log(album_photos);
    for (var i = 0; i < album_photos.length; i++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        var imagewrap = document.createElement('div');
        imagewrap.className = "image-wrap";
        var imagemenu = document.createElement('div');
        imagemenu.className = "image-menu";
        var imagemenuimg1 = document.createElement('img');
        imagemenuimg1.src = "img/edit_img.png";
        var imagemenuimg2 = document.createElement('img');
        imagemenuimg2.src = "img/close.png";
        var imagewrapimg = document.createElement('img');
        imagewrapimg.className = "thumbnail";
        imagewrapimg.src = "admin/album_photos/" + album_photos[i].Image_Path;
        document.getElementById("tiare").appendChild(td);
        td.appendChild(imagewrap);
        imagewrap.appendChild(imagemenu);
        imagemenu.appendChild(imagemenuimg1);
        imagemenu.appendChild(imagemenuimg2);
        imagewrap.appendChild(imagewrapimg);
    }
}
xhr2.send(null);
```

What I get is this in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
xhr2.onreadystatechange
[Object, Object]
[Object, Object]
```

This is my HTML on which the elements are appended:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- <div class="big_image" id="drop_zone">
            <img src="" id="big_img" />
        </div -->
        <div class="images_holder">
            <div class="header">Album Name - Photo Album    <span class="close"><img src="img/close.png" /></span>

            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <table width="80%">
                    <tr id="tiare">
                        <td>
                            <div class="image-wrap">
                                <div class="image-menu">
                                    <img src="img/edit_img.png" />
                                    <img src="img/close.png" />
                                </div>
                                <img src="img/anger.jpg" class="thumbnail" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="drop_zone">Drag/Drop images to upload.</div>
        <div style="height: 30px; width: 80%; color: white; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
            <p id="progress_bar" style="width: 0%; background-color: red;"></p>
        </div>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Another problem that's occurring is that their are 2 objects coming with 2 more objects in them where as it should show only 1 object with 2 more objects in it.

HOw can I solve this problem?

**Note: I have to use pure Javascript no jQuery allowed :P.**

Comment: please, show response text

Comment: @VasilVanchuk The thing that I am getting is the response text. :P

Comment: At first - you didn't check readyState ( like xhr2.readyState==4 ) to be shore, that  all response loaded. Did you know? Second -- please add response body to your question - it help to understand structure and values of variables

Comment: Didn't knew it was this small mistake. Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: var album_photos = eval(xhr2.responseText);
    console.log(album_photos);

if so - i see error, but i didn't saw album_photos value

Comment: Please show `responseText`....

Answer (score 0):

there are two possible reasons for this error as far as I recall, or generally, errors with appendChild.

1. the DOM has not finished load ---> try putting your code, (any code that appends to the DOM rendered via HTML) inside jQuery's document ready. or window.onload (for pure javascript even in the controller.
2. the second reason is that something other than an html node is being passed. 
   I had this happen when I had a function which returned an array of nodes to be inserted. Therefore, when it returned an array of only one item, I mistakingly thought of it as a node and could not figure out why

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, use jQuery.

If not, use at least NOT `eval`, it can be spoofed and FUBAR things too easily.

Should be using this:

```
var album_photos = JSON.parse(xhr2.responseText);
```